# Logging into website with script using python requests

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am attempting to login to a website using python and it seems the best way to do this is with the requests library.  My problem is interpreting what I need to send to the website in the payload.  When I look at the HTML for the site, I see this:

```
<script>
cdc = typeof cdc == "undefined" ? {} : cdc;
cdc.login = typeof cdc.login == "undefined" ? {} : cdc.login;
cdc.login.prefsObj = {
  login_showErrorMsg : false,
  login_show_smtryno : false,
  login_action       : "https://sso.cisco.com/autho/login/loginaction.html",
  login_user_name    : "userid",
  login_password_name: "password",
  login_domain       : "https://www.cisco.com",
  login_target       : "",
  login_smauthreason : "",
  login_smquerydata  : "",
  login_smagentname  : "",
  login_postpreservationdata :"",
  login_SMENC        : "",
  login_SMLOCALE     : ""
};
</script>
```

Is this telling me I should create a payload with the dict entry 'login_user_name' or is it telling me I should use 'userid' as the name of the dict entry?

Am I posting this to the URL that displays the login page or am I posting it to what it shows as the 'login_action' URL?

Thanks...

Comment: You need to post the **that** page, and you need to provide your login username in the `login_user_name` field. The word `userid` there is just a placeholder to show you that you're supposed to enter your username /  password in those fields.

Comment: That is what I figured but when I send the post, i get HTML back that says the username or password is incorrect however I know the username and password is good....

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you need to post to the URL in the 'login_action' field.  You also need to use 'userid' and 'password' in the payload, not the stuff on the left.  The final payload needs to look like:

```
payload = {
    'userid' : 'myusername',
    'password' : 'mypassword',
    'target' : '',
    'smauthreason' : '',
    'smquerydata' : '',
    'smagentname' : '',
    'postpreservationdata' : '',
    'SMENC' : '',
    'SMLOCALE' : ''
}
```

Now the problem is that the data I get back says I was unable to be redirected...